# Add field to screen "New content type" in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a drupal app and I want to have a field as checkbox, so, when I create/edit a content type, it appears like the title and the description, and if I check it, all of the nodes with that type will have that field checked. 
Some ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to the form where you want to add the field.

View source, you will get `form_id` there.

Get the `form_id` to use in one of the following form alter hooks.

Alter the form using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Comment: @Junjo: Is this solution to your question?